# Crawled (403) Error while login to glassdoor.com using scrapy in python. Need Solution?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Here is the complete code, there is error "***Crawled (403)***", when I run the code. If I bypass the HTTP error by using **HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES  =[403]** in setting.py, then code start working.

But I need the **solution of login** into the website.

```
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from scrapy.http import Request,FormRequest

class MoorSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'moor'
allowed_domains = ['glassdoor.com']
start_urls = ['https://www.glassdoor.com/profile/login_input.htm']
page_number = 2

    
    def parse(self,response):
        token = response.xpath('.//*[@name="gdToken"]/@value').extract()
        # print(token)
        yield FormRequest('https://www.glassdoor.com/profile/ajax/loginSecureAjax.htm', formdata={'username':'likej41679@94jo.com','password':'1a2b3c4d','gdToken':token}, callback=self.startscraper)
    
    
    def startscraper(self,response):
        yield Request('https://www.glassdoor.com/Explore/browse-companies.htm?overall_rating_low=3.5&page=1&isHiringSurge=0&locId=1282&locType=S&locName=North%20Carolina,%20US,%20US', callback=self.startscraper1)
    
    
    
    def startscraper1(self,response):
        urls = response.css('.col-12.my-0.mt-sm.mt-sm-std.order-5 a::attr(href)').extract()
        # print(next_page)
        for url in urls:
            url1 = urljoin('https://www.glassdoor.com/', url)
            yield Request(url1, callback=self.DetailPage)
    
        # next_page = 'https://www.glassdoor.com/Explore/browse-companies.htm?overall_rating_low=3.5&page='+str(MoorSpider.page_number)+'&isHiringSurge=0&locId=1282&locType=S&locName=North%20Carolina,%20US,%20US'
        next_page = 'https://www.glassdoor.com/Explore/browse-companies.htm?overall_rating_low=3.5&page=' + str(
            MoorSpider.page_number) + '&isHiringSurge=0&locId=1282&locType=S&locName=North%20Carolina,%20US,%20US'
        if MoorSpider.page_number <= 2:
            MoorSpider.page_number += 1
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.startscraper1)
    
    
    def DetailPage(self,response):
        Company_Website=response.css('[data-test="employer-website"]::text').get()
        Company_Revenue = response.css('[data-test="employer-revenue"]::text').get()
        Company_Description = response.css('span[data-test="employerDescription"]::text').get()
        Company_Mission = response.css('span[data-test="employerMission"]::text').get()
    
        yield {
            'Company_Website':Company_Website,
            'Company_Revenue':Company_Revenue,
            'Company_Description':Company_Description,
            'Company_Mission':Company_Mission,
    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your existing `parse` method with the following one in order for it to work. Turn out that your token variable holds nothing as it is generated dynamically. You can however parse the value of `gdToken` out of some script tag.

```
def parse(self,response):
    token = response.css('body').re(r"gdToken\":\"(.*?)\",")[0]
    yield FormRequest('https://www.glassdoor.com/profile/ajax/loginSecureAjax.htm', formdata={'username':'likej41679@94jo.com','password':'1a2b3c4d','gdToken':token}, callback=self.startscraper)
```